# Angular 2 - misspelled selector/component tag and forcing error messages

Tags: angular

I am a newbie to Angular2.

I am not sure of the most preferred term for referring to  a selector/component tag. An example of what I am calling selector/component tag is the `app-menu` tag below in the HTML sample. I want any misspellings of one of these tags in an HTML fragment to force some kind of error message when it is encountered.

Let’s say I misspell the `app-menu` selector `apppppppppppp-menu` (with a bunch of extra p’s). You should assume I have a component with `selector="app-menu"` but I just misspelled it in the HTML.

I am using `node server` to start and run my application. Is there a way to force an error message if my HTML has a selector/component tag that does exist because I misspelled it?

Something like a compile error if I misspell something in a Java application?

Currently my application just doesn’t load (Loading….., so it just gets stuck on “Loading…”) which isn’t that helpful.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks, Andrew.

```html
<div *ngIf="case" class="ui-g"> 
    <div class="ui-md-2" style="border-right: 1px solid orange;">
        <app-menu></app-menu>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check browser's console? It usually displays some info, more or less intuitive, about the encountered error.

Comment: The problem is that it isn't provoking any kind of an error message. So the browser's console doesn't help much. An answer that I got in the angular google discussion group [Angular](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/evaVw_7eQ_s) leads me to believe that there really isn't an easy way around this. There is no way for angular to know that it isn't a non angular custom element. It was suggested that I look at something like [codelyzer](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer).

Comment: You should be getting a `"apppppppppppp-menu" is not a known element..` error in the browser console, that's weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it isn't provoking any kind of an error message. So the browser's console doesn't help much. An answer that I got in the angular google discussion group Angular leads me to believe that there really isn't an easy way around this. There is no way for angular to know that it isn't a non angular custom element. It was suggested that I look at something like codelyzer.